Random caterwauling by neutered female cat. Any known explanation?
I'm not convinced this one has an answer...
I've seen this in many cats, but over the years my cat has had a habit of every now and then uttering a series of four to eight yowls in what sounds to me like a complaining tone. This may be repeated after a delay of a few minutes. It doesn't seem to be directed at humans since it's often at the other end of the house.
If she wasn't fixed, I'd wonder if she was announcing that she was in heat. But she is, so she isn't, though she could be confused about that.
It's a fairly common behavior among housecats. I've heard proposed translations from "I'm lonely" to "I like the echoes" to "I'm uncomfortable or frustrated" to "I will now sing the Song of my People".
Has anyone come up with an authoritative explanation or set of explanations for this behavior? Or should we just continue to write this off as "it just seemed like the right thing to do at the time"?
